# OperationalError: no such module: fts4 ? Also No Extensions Available in SQLite in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, full-text-search, operationalerror

I am trying to use fuzzymatcher, but when  I run the code I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: no such module: fts4
```

Also, I tried to load the extensions by placing the latest sqlite.dll file in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs` by using the code

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
for (val,) in cur.execute('pragma compile_options'): 
    print (val)
```

but no extensions show up and returns the following code,

```
COMPILER=msvc-1916
THREADSAFE=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the Steps I Followed & Extensions got enabled,

```
1. Update the Sqlite by following on anaconda:
conda install -c anaconda sqlite

2.Download and Extract the following folder
https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw/releases/download/3.33.0-r1/apsw-3.33.0-r1.zip

3. Run Anaconda & following command in that folder:
python setup.py install test
```